# Adding extra data to HttpResponseMessage/Exception (throwing an exception with multiple arguments)

Tags: vb.net, exception, httpresponse

I have an errorbox in my web application that appears whenever a certain type of exception is caught. At the moment the exception is thrown with a string, that I can then insert into my errorbox. I would now like to also give it e.g. a color, so that I (in case of an exception) can set both the color and the text of the errorbox.

Once I catch an exception I throw a new HttpResponseException with a ReasonPhrase and a StatusCode. These are both used whenever I handle the exception. I actually use a custom exception type that currently only has a message called MyException in this example.
It looks like this:

```
Public Class MyException
    Inherits Exception

    Public Sub New(message As String)
        MyBase.New(message)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I've heard about using some sort of Data or Content property for the HttpResponseMessage, but I don't quite understand how I would use that.

Here's the vb.net code for the catching of an exception:

```
Catch myEx As MyException
    Dim resp = New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed) With
    {
        .ReasonPhrase = myEx.Message,
        .StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed
    }

    Throw New HttpResponseException(resp)
```

When I throw the exception to start with, I would want to do something like:

```
Throw New MyException("Some error text", 5, "yellow", true)
```

For instance.
And then insert those extra arguments into the HttpResponseMessage somehow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Just add properties e.g. for color to `MyException` and enhance the constructor with these parameters.

Comment: Yes, that will give me a myEx.Color property that I can use just like the myEx.Message property, but how do I add it to the HttpResponseMessage?
Later on I catch the HttpResponseException and would like to extract the color property then - just like I can with the Message from the ReasonPhrase property of HttpResponseMessage.

Comment: Can I initialize a new instance of the Exception (MyBase) object using system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo instead of a string somehow?

Comment: I don´t understand your last comment completely. But you can set your exception as `InnerException` of the `HttpResponseException`. Or - instead of inhering from `Exception` your exception could inherit from `HttpResponseException` and you add the extra properties.